# Why this method returns always -1

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, return, return-value

```
  private int deleter(BSTNode node, int key) {
    if(node.key==key){
        if(node.right==null && node.left==null){
            node=null;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if(key<node.key){
        node=node.left;
        deleter(node,key);

    }
    else {
        node=node.right;
        deleter(node,key);
    }


    return -1;
}
```

Why is this method returns always -1  .Should it return 0 when it found exact node ? It goes again this block and then return -1

```
 else {
        node=node.right;
        deleter(node,key);
 }
```

Comment: That's because the only return statement from your recursion code is -1. Instead of just calling deleter, just add return statement in front and remove the last `return -1;` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursives calls effectivlt returns `0` but you are ignoring that return value from the caller :

```
private int deleter(BSTNode node, int key) {
    if(node.key == key){
        if(node.right == null && node.left == null){
            node = null;
            return 0;
        }
    }else if(key < node.key){
        node = node.left;
        return deleter(node,key);      // return here    
    }else {
        node = node.right;
        return deleter(node,key);      // return here
    }   
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: so what sholud i do , if i delete recursive function which returned, it will okay ?

Comment: Your last sentence is incorrect. If `(node.key == key)` is true but `(node.right == null && node.left == null)` is false, this method will return nothing. Therefore the code won't pass compilation without the last return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You ignore the values returned by the recursive calls:

```
private int deleter(BSTNode node, int key) {
    if(node.key==key){
        if(node.right==null && node.left==null){
            node=null;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if(key<node.key){
        node=node.left;
        return deleter(node,key);

    }
    else {
        node=node.right;
        return deleter(node,key);
    }


    return -1;
}
```

EDIT: you should add some null checks to this code, or you may end up with `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Why would you need return -1?

Comment: @SMA the method should return -1 if you don't find a match, or if you find a match, but don't set `node` to `null`.